# getting all values in the row

Tags: javascript

```
var patientInfo = {}   
patientInfo.patientID = row.patientID;
patientInfo.firstName = row.firstName;
patientInfo.lastName = row.lastName;
patientInfo.dateOfBirth = row.DateOfBirth;
patientInfo.age = row.age;
patientInfo.gender = row.gender;
```

When I print I `patientInfo`, I get only one row's data... how can I get all row's data?

Comment: you mean you get only one row among those or you get all those data concatenated in one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean. But assuming you are having this code in a loop, you are always overwriting the `patientInfo` data. Add them to an array:

```
infos = []

for(.....) {
    var patientInfo = {}   
    patientInfo.patientID = row.patientID;
    patientInfo.firstName = row.firstName;
    patientInfo.lastName = row.lastName;
    patientInfo.dateOfBirth = row.DateOfBirth;
    patientInfo.age = row.age;
    patientInfo.gender = row.gender;

    infos.push(patientInfo)
}
```

It would be good to know here `row` is coming from. Maybe you could just do:

```
infos = []

for(.....) {
    infos.push(row)
}
```

or maybe you don't have to do this at all. You have to provide more information.

More information => better answers.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over properties in an object, use `for in`.

```
for (var property in patientInfo) {
   alert(property);
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that if someone has augmented `Object`, its enumerable properties will be iterated over too.

You can mitigate this by using `hasOwnProperty()`.

```
for (var property in patientInfo) {
   if ( ! patientInfo.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       continue;
   }
   alert(property);
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify you own `toString()` method which formats the values however you want. Be sure to return a string.